# ViewPager child view method callin automatic?

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager

I implemented View Pager with fragment child A/B/C. To get selection of default Fragment(say A) I use `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position)` and it work fine. But on this Second Fragment (B) view methods `onViewCreated` and `setUserVisibleHint` calling automatically.

Is there any way to prevent this !

Answer (score 0):

You can try invoking `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)`, which will no longer pre-load non-visible Fragments. The default value for the off-screen page limit is 1, so that should be the reason why the onViewCreated() and setUserVisibleHint() methods are being called for your other fragments.

Comment: minimum limit is 1 to set.

Comment: any other suggestion !

Comment: The source code _does_ force the off-screen limit to 1. In terms of suggestions, my recommendation is that if you must use ViewPager, then modify your code with the assumption that your fragments may be created under any circumstances. Otherwise, you may need to consider implementing your own version of ViewPager.